# External command in PowerShell - where Java

Tags: powershell, cmd

This works in command prompt:

```
where Java
```

In PowerShell `where` is an alias for `Where-Object`. I tried to stop parsing:

```
--% where Java
```

This does not work, also tried storing as a variable:

```
$StopParser = "--%"
$StopParser where Java
```

This returns the error: `'Unexpected token 'where' in expression or statement'.`

How can I use the where command in PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a question of parsing, but of command origins.  The [`where`](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html) cmd command is an executable in System32 that searches your current directory and the PATH environment variable for a pattern:

```
WHERE Java
```

is equivalent to:

```
cmd.exe /C where.exe Java
```

---

The link I provided shows an equivalent command for `powershell`:

```
(Get-Command -Name $file).Definition
```

or you can alternatively call the executable the same way:

```
where.exe Java
```

---

For quite a few cmd tools, this is the same paradigm: an executable in System32.

Comment: It's not internal (under Windows 7, at least) [`COPY` and `DIR` are internal in the sense that they are code within `cmd.exe`]; it's implemented as `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe`. It can be invoked from within PowerShell as `where.exe`, explicitly including the file extension to override the internal alias.

Comment: `WHERE Java` isn't quite the same as `cmd.exe /C where.exe Java`, although the practical effect/output is the same. (They're not precisely equivalent because you're spinning up a copy [unnecessarily] of `cmd.exe`.) It's more accurate to say that `WHERE Java` is equivalent to `where.exe Java` (as you note at the end of your answer).